# N00B help - script to check if inputs can make a right-angled triangle. Messed up my alert and don't know if i have variables?

Tags: javascript

This is mostly code written for my by the teacher. I've tried messing about with the first alert to make it work but I can't get it running. I was wonder, in this alert, it is asking for a, b, c etc - where are they coming from? I'm supposed to be able to type in a length in each box to see if that mnakes a right-angled triangle.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Area of triangle</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html ; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

function Pathago(a,b,c) {



alert(a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ((a*a)+(b*b)) = (c*c)); //_for testing purposes_ - I take it this is the pythagoras formula but it won't run and I can't figure out how to write properly. I'm getting an error about the equation operator.

if ((a*a)+(b*b)==(c*c)){return true;}
else {return false;}
}

function checkForTriangle(){
num1 = parseFloat(document.triangleForm.number1.value);
num2 = parseFloat(document.triangleForm.number2.value);
num3 = parseFloat(document.triangleForm.number3.value);

sideA = Math.floor((num1 + num2));
sideB = Math.floor((num1 + num3));
sideC = Math.floor((num2 + num3));

if (sideA > num3 && sideB > num2 && sideC > num1) {alert("These 3 sides CAN be a triangle");}
if (Pathago(num1,num2,num3) || Pathago(num1,num2,num3) || Pathago(num2,num3,num1)){
}

else {
alert("These 3 sides CANNOT be a right-angle triangle");
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="triangleForm" action="">
<p>Enter number 1: <input type="text" name="number1"><br>
<p>Enter number 2: <input type="text" name="number2"><br>
<p>Enter number 3: <input type="text" name="number3"><br>
<input type="button" value="Triangle or Not" onclick="checkfortriangle();">
</form>
</head>

<body>
```

Comment: you might try this example: http://jsfiddle.net/RRgSW/

Comment: What error are you seeing?  Unless you add more detail, "I can't get it running" gives us little to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue (see comment above), but your alert statement contains this invalid expression:

```
((a*a)+(b*b)) = (c*c)
```

You probably meant `==`; it's interpreting this as an attempt to assign `(c*c)` to `((a*a)+(b*b))`, which breaks because the latter is not a valid variable name.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ((a*a)+(b*b)) = (c*c));
```

is an invalid expression.  This one should work: (note the == operator which checks if two values are the same

```
alert(a + ',' + b + ',' + c + (((a*a)+(b*b)) == (c*c)));
```

Here is a fully working sample:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYwXwp

(There were numerous issues with your code, I've fixed some of them)